# How to extract the words through pattern matching?

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = "praveen is a good boy";
my @try = split(/([a,e,i,o,u]).*\1/,$string);
print "@try\n";
```

I am trying to print all words containing 2 adjacent vowels in a given string.
o/p : has to be "praveen" and "good" .

I tried with the negate exp [^] to split and give only the 2 adjacent vowels.

Comment: Do the adjacent vowels need to be doubles "aa", "ee", "oo". Or can we also have "ea", "ou" etc?

Comment: It can be any combination but the adjacent has to be a vowel

Comment: OK, thank you for clarification, I have adjusted my answer. You may want to provide more example data in the OP, as it only has double vowels, and your first attempt at regex looks like you are trying for doubles too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Perl function `split` isn't a great fit for finding a list of matches. Instead, I would recommend using the regex modifier `g`. To process all the matches, you can either loop, using e.g. `while`, or you can assign the list of matches in one go.

The following example should match all words in a string which contain two adjacent vowels:

```
my $string = "praveen is a good boy"; 
while ( $string =~ /(\w*[aeiou]{2}\w*)/g ) { 
  print "$1\n" 
}
```

Output:

```
praveen
good
```

You could also do this:

```
my @matches = ( $string =~ /\w*[aeiou]{2}\w*/g );
```

and process the result similar to how you were processing `@try` in the OP.

Comment: Better `\w*`, no? Otherwise it wouldn't work as expected with examples similar to: `aaron is a good boy`

Comment: This doesn't handle cases where the last word has doubled vowels.  You might do `$string =~ /(\w+([aeiou]){2}(?:\w+|\b))/g` which then works with `"praveen is a good boy, hoot, hoo."`

Comment: Thanks for suggested improvements. I'm not entirely sure if the vowel matching is correct yet, either. "Two adjacent vowels" is OP's wording, but "double vowels" seems like the goal from original regex.

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like..

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str 
   = "praveen is a good boy\n"
   . "aaron is a good boy\n"
   . "praveen and aaron are good, hoot, ho"
   ;

while ($str =~ /(\w*([aeiou])\2(?:\w*))/g) {
       print $1, "\n";
}
```

Regular expression:

```
(               group and capture to \1:
 \w*            word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more times)
   (            group and capture to \2:
    [aeiou]     any character of: 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'
   )            end of \2
   \2           what was matched by capture \2
    (?:         group, but do not capture:
      \w*       word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more times)
    )           end of grouping
)               end of \1
```

Which is basically the same as doing `/(\w*([aeiou])[aeiou]+(?:\w*))/`

Output:

```
praveen
good
aaron
good
praveen
aaron
good
hoot
```

Comment: This is actually extracting words of 4+ letters which contain a vowel  somewhere in middle (character 1 to n-2 where n is length of word). . . try "elephants are purple"

Comment: Try your regex with "elephants are purple" and then mine . . . there is a difference. Unfortunately all the sample sentences have 4+ letters for all the matching words. So change "ho" to "hoo", and other variants. Note my regex wasn't right to start either, and it needed someone to point it out to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = "praveen is a good boy";
my @try = split(/\s/,$string);
for(@try) {
#    if(/[a,e,i,o,u]{2}/) {
    if(/[aeiou]{2}/) { # edited after Birei's comment
        print "$_\n";
    };
};
```

First argumant of "split" is a delimiter. Split splits (-8

Comment: Inside character classes you don't have to separate each one. And that way it could give bad results, like: `prave,n`.